# Can I put h tag in footer?

Tags: html

I have a list of replies to topic. Each reply is with article tag and doesn't really need a title and the layout looks nice without a title. But in html5 outline test, each of the replies is a "undefined section". So I am thinking to put this in footer:

```
<h3>Reply-$id</h3>
```

Is this invalid or a bad practice of html5?

Comment: That's an even worse practice than not having a title IMO.

Comment: Read http://html5doctor.com/outlines/ and note: "If you don’t want these headings to be visible, you can always hide them with CSS."

Answer (score 3):

There's a relevant thread on the W3C HTML working group mailing list at present - it starts at http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2013Jan/0109.html - where the prevailing opinion seems to be that using the `<article>` element for comments/replies is not helpful and the recommendation should be removed from the spec, and `<ol>/<li>` recommended instead.

This would have the effect of removing individual comments from the document outline unless you explicitly provided a heading for each one.

Moving on to directly address your question, personally, I disagree with BoltClock - I think that's fine as a heading, and I don't see a problem with putting it in a footer if you believe that's where it belongs. Remember that comments/replies often cross-reference to one another via their reply number, especially when repliers don't provide a title, so to be able to find the cross-referenced reply by means of a contents list/document outline would be a useful effect. And yet the reply number is a kind of subordinate metadata of the reply, so containing it in a footer does not seem unreasonable.

However, if a user was finding the reply by cross reference via, say, a screen reader, they'd want the text of the reply to follow the heading, so in this case you should place the `<footer>` before the text of the reply. There's nothing wrong with doing that, although it may negate your presentational intent.

Comment: You have a point there - I guess I'm just not used to seeing footers containing little more than headings, but as far as HTML5 semantics are concerned it may be entirely commonplace.